# Ruby with Rspec - How is this test passing?

Tags: ruby, rspec

This test passes validations, but how?

```
#Rspec 
it "handles a case with an answer > 1 distance to the left" do
  nearest_larger([8,2,4,3], 2).should == 0
end

#Function
def nearest_larger(arr, idx)
  diff = 1

  loop do
    left  = idx - diff
    right = idx + diff

    if (left >= 0) && (arr[left] > arr[idx])
      return left 
    elsif (right < arr.length) && (arr[right] > arr[idx])
      return right 
    elsif (left > 0) && (right >= arr.length)
      return nil
    end

  diff += 1
  end
end
```

I'm working through some ruby examples and I can't understand how this test passes validation. Where is `0` being returned from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `idx` is 2 and `diff` is 2 (that is, on your second loop), `left` is `2 - 2 = 0`, and `arr[0] == 8`, which is greater than `arr[2] == 4`. The function then returns `left`, which is zero.

Comment: `left = idx - diff` `diff` = 1 thus `left` == `1`

Comment: You my friend are awesome. Thank you. I see it now! +1 on the comment. How's tech scene in AZ? I want to move out there.